# SSH port not working

Tags: networking

So I nmap'd my ct and for some reason `7000/tcp open  afs3-fileserver` is running on the port I need. Is there anyway to disable the afs3-fileserver?

Edit:
The log shows this constantly everytime I try to log in.

```
Dec 18 21:41:01 steamcmd CRON[9477]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Dec 18 21:41:01 steamcmd CRON[9477]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 18 21:41:01 steamcmd CRON[9477]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: What does the SSH port have to do with `afs3-fileserver`? What's your actual question here?

Comment: Yes, disable it.

Comment: Well how would I disable afs3 since It is running on the same port I need ssh to run on.

Comment: The errors you show are from crond.  Those should not affect how/why ssh does not let you log in.  Perhaps you should check what `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p ANOTHERPORT `reports when you try to log in via `ssh HOSTNAME -p ANOTHERPORT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessarily `afs3-fileserver` that is running on the port.  That is just the name assigned to port 7000, as that is the port number that was assigned for this specific service.

You will need to check what process is actually running on the port by looking locally on the server, with something like:

```
# netstat -tanp | grep :7000
```

The above would print all the processes using this port, including the PID and name of the process in the LISTEN state that is watching for new requests.

```
# fuser 7000/tcp
```

`fuser` also can be used to see the PIDs of the processes using that tcp port, and then you'll need to check the ps output what are those processes.  Without knowing what that process is, and how it was started, it may not be trivial to stop it forever - even if you kill it, it could be restarted right away by the system.

Comment: Well going on the local box it shows sshd running instead of afs3-fileserver, but why would it not be letting me into the server? I also edited the first post with what the log shows.

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that another server was using that port. Thanks for the help!